# How to start an audio stream from URL with an offset with MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

For a file the `MediaPlayer` has a method

```
setDataSource (FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)
```

in which an offset can be set.

How can I do that for a stream from a URL?

I guess I should use

```
setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers)
```

but what header should I set for an offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just seek to that location once your MediaPlayer instance is prepared. Something like:

```
final int seekLocation = 30000; // 30 seconds
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.seek(seekLocation);
    mp.start();
  }
};
```

(I can't test this code, so maybe it won't compile but hopefully you get the gist).

Comment: yes. I had forgotten that question. That's what I did in the end. Thx